# USB-C to HDMI cable length restrictions

Tags: usb, hdmi, cable, usb-c, rj-45

I'm curious how USB-C to HDMI cables lengths restrictions work? I know USB-C has a reliability restriction of 13ft and HDMI can run up to 50ft. However, if you have a USB-C to HDMI passive cable, what happens? Is signal degradation limited by the USB-C restrictions or the HDMI restrictions?

Same question for USB-C to RJ-45 connections as well.

Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: Logic would say you add the two together [maintaining each segment's max], like running USB 2.0 down repeaters, but I have no proof.

Comment: Is it an active converter or a passive adapter?

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. This will be for passive cables